# I use koa,koa-router,koa-body in my program.But the value of this.reauest.body is "{}"

Tags: forms, koa, koa-router

I use "form" to send data to my webserver.
front-end:

```
<form action="http://localhost:3131/users" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_blank">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="age">Age:</label>
        <input type="text" id="age" name="age"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="wl">Wl:</label>
        <input type="text" id="wl" name="wl"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

back-end code,
[Github link](https://github.com/dlau/koa-body):

```
var app     = require('koa')(),
router  = require('koa-router')(),
koaBody = require('koa-body')();

router.post('/users', koaBody,
  function *(next) {
    console.log(this.request.body);
    // => POST body
    this.body = JSON.stringify(this.request.body);
  }
);

app.use(router.routes());

app.listen(3131);
console.log('curl -i http://localhost:3131/users -d "name=test"');
```

But the result is --> this.request.body is {}.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `multipart/form-data` as your form data encoding, so in your server code you should pass the correct option to `koa-body` constructor.

```
kaoBody = require('koa-body)({ multipart: true });
```

Comment: Thank you ! now--> {"fields":{"name":"qq","age":"dd","wl":"dd"},"files":{}}